# Compile LaTeX code in verbatim/lstlisting

Tags: listings, compiling, external-files

For a presentation (in `beamer`) with the topic *How to use LaTeX for your thesis* at my university, I wanted to add lots of LaTeX code snippets and compile them. At the moment, I have a separate `.tex` file for each example and compile each file individually. Then I include the necessary lines (e.g. without preamble) with `lstlisting` and include the compiled PDF via `\includegraphics`.

This is quite cumbersome. Sure, I can automate the compilation of dozens of files, e.g. with `latexmk`, but I have to keep track off and open so many files. Just typing the same code in the presentation twice, once verbatim and once as plain code so as to let LaTeX compile this snippet, is the best option, but then I would have to reset all fonts to standard `article` instead of `beamer`, and local settings (e.g. with `enumitem`) may conflict with other settings from `beamer`.

Do you have an idea on what the best solution could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `tcblisting` from the `tcolorbox` package. It allows to automatically show the source and the result.

Here a short example to get you started, but have a look in the documentation, as it comes with tons of options to customise the result:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tcblisting}{before lower=\rmfamily}
\LaTeX\ example with serif font like in article 
\end{tcblisting}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tcblisting}{
  listing and comment,
  pdf comment,
  freeze pdf,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is it. It even allows for syntax highlighting and whatnot.

Comment: @Gargantuar Have fun with your new toy :)